How to encode data passed to/from remote ONNX models via HTTP?
Assume we have a remote ONNX ML model (running on onnxruntime), and we want to expose it via a REST API for making predictions.
How to properly encode the inputs/outputs passed in HTTP messages?
As onnxruntime has different types (primarily tensors, maps and sequences are used), I wonder if there's a unified way to do it. JSON? Protobuf? Some other format? And do I write my own encoder/decoder for different OrtValues?
Possible scenario: 
Input:
N tensors
Output:
A tensor of N predicted labels, and a sequence of maps of probabilities for each label
The question is not language specific.
Thanks
